# FirebaseStorage with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

Im new to firebase and i wasnt able to figure out what kinda parameter i shud pass to the putfile in the
following code , and is there any tutorials or proper documentation for firebase with flutter?

Implemented code

```
import "dart:io";
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart";
import "package:flutter/widgets.dart";

class uploadApp extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>_uploadApp(); 
}

class _uploadApp extends State<uploadApp>{

  var count=1;
  final File file = File("images/ts2.jpg");
  final FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage(storageBucket:"gs://console.firebase.google.com/project/baby-name-4ef54/storage/baby-name-4ef54.appspot.com");
  StorageUploadTask _uploadTask;

  void firebasebackend(){
    String filePath = "images/$count.jpg";
    setState(() {
      _uploadTask = _storage.ref().child(filePath).putFile(file);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title:"upload",
      home:Material(
        child:Container(child:Center(
          child:
           Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 300.0,
                height: 300.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(300.0)),
                  image:DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("images/ts2.jpg"),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover
                  )
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child:Text("Upload"),
                  onPressed: (){
                    firebasebackend();
                    setState(){
                  count=count+1;
                       };     
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

> 'package:firebase_storage/src/storage_reference.dart': Failed assertion: line 62 pos 12: 'file.existsSync()': is not true.

What should I do to just upload an image directly from a folder to the firebase storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the code of `firebase_storage` plugin:

```
  /// Asynchronously uploads a file to the currently specified
  /// [StorageReference], with an optional [metadata].
  StorageUploadTask putFile(File file, [StorageMetadata metadata]) {
    assert(file.existsSync());
    final _StorageFileUploadTask task =
        _StorageFileUploadTask._(file, _firebaseStorage, this, metadata);
    task._start();
    return task;
  }
```

Takes a `file` as a parameter and a variable of type `StorageMetadata` as an **optional** parameter.

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_storage/lib/src/storage_reference.dart#L61

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-io/File-class.html

Comment: yea but which/what file shud i use , like the filePath i used for the "child()" denotes the file path in the firebaseStorage , so what does this file denote?

Comment: does it denote the file that is going to be created for the given address?,i gave the jpg file itself is given in the "filePath"

Comment: you need to use a file object example: `File tempImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);` if you used  image_picker plugin to get images from gallery then the methd `pickImage` returns a File object which you can use in `putFile`

Comment: in the `filepath` you add the path that will be in the storage console for example the path can be, child("images") and then you create a new file object that will contain the jpg image and add it to `putFile`

Comment: ive edited the question , it throws an exception as shown below

Comment: @HDD what is your question? Ask another question and link it here so I can check it

Comment: @PeterHaddad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62045943/unhandled-exception-packagefirebase-storage-src-storage-reference-dart-fail......please help me out,save my life

Comment: @HDD I need someone to save my life :(

Comment: @PeterHaddad, oo, come on sir, please suggest me a way out of this :)

Comment: For those who stumbled upon this looking for implementing metadata directly, you can do `var metadata = StorageMetadata(customMetadata: {'somemetadata': 'yesIam});` and then `StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(imageFile, metadata);`

Answer (score 0):

From the error message you get, it looks like there is no file at `File("images/ts2.jpg");` on your phone, which means the SDK can't find any data to upload to Cloud Storage.

In general I'd be suspicious of the relative path you're using here. The [example that comes with the Firebase Storage SDK](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_storage/example/lib/main.dart#L63) creates a file at an absolute path in the temp dir with `final File file = await File('${systemTempDir.path}/foo$uuid.txt').create();`, and I'd recommend using absolute paths on the file system too.

You will need to find the absolute path of the image you want to upload, either by browsing the file system of your device, or by taking the absolute path from the gallery or camera. For example, if you use a [file picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker), you can get the file with:

```
File file = await FilePicker.getFile();
```

Comment: the absolute path in my phone?

Answer (score 0):

This might seem very trivial, but Peter Haddad pointed out in the comments of his post

> That's probably because there is no image with that path...

which is exactly the problem why I had this error. 
My mistake was, that I assumed an error is thrown when the `File` object is created and a non-existent path was used to create this object. 
However, this is not the case. Therefore, **make sure to verify the File object refers to the correct path**.