# Unhandled Exception: 'package:firebase_storage/src/storage_reference.dart': Failed assertion: line 62 pos 12: 'file.existsSync()': is not true

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

Unhandled Exception: 'package:firebase_storage/src/storage_reference.dart': Failed assertion: line 62 pos 12: 'file.existsSync()': is not true.

On naviagtion, code in 'package:firebase_storage/src/storage_reference.dart' is :

```
  assert(file.existsSync());
  final _StorageFileUploadTask task =
      _StorageFileUploadTask._(file, _firebaseStorage, this, metadata);
  task._start();
  return task;
}
```

---

Code of uplading image to firebase storage:

```
void _selectImage(Future<File> pickImage, int imageNumber) async {
    File tempImg = await pickImage;
    switch (imageNumber) {
      case 1:
        setState(() => _image1 = tempImg);
        break;
      case 2:
        setState(() => _image2 = tempImg);
        break;
      case 3:
        setState(() => _image3 = tempImg);
        break;
      case 4:
        setState(() => _image4 = tempImg);
        break;
    }
  }

  Widget _displayChild1() {
    if (_image1 == null) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14, 70, 14, 70),
        child: new Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(1),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Image.file(
        _image1,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        width: double.infinity,
      );
    }
  }
```

```
 String imageUrl1;
        String imageUrl2;
        String imageUrl3;
        String imageUrl4;
        //  String imageUrl3;
        final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
        final String picture1 = "1${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}.jpg";
        StorageUploadTask task1 = storage.ref().child(picture1).putFile(_image1);
        final String picture2 = "2${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}.jpg";
        StorageUploadTask task2 = storage.ref().child(picture2).putFile(_image2);
        final String picture3 = "3${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}.jpg";
        StorageUploadTask task3 = storage.ref().child(picture3).putFile(_image3);
        final String picture4 = "4${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}.jpg";
        StorageUploadTask task4 = storage.ref().child(picture4).putFile(_image4);


        StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot1 =
        await task1.onComplete.then((sanapshot) => sanapshot);
        StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot2 =
        await task2.onComplete.then((sanapshot) => sanapshot);
        StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot3 =
        await task3.onComplete.then((sanapshot) => sanapshot);


        task4.onComplete.then((snapshot4) async {
          imageUrl1 = await snapshot1.ref.getDownloadURL();
          imageUrl2 = await snapshot2.ref.getDownloadURL();
          imageUrl3 = await snapshot3.ref.getDownloadURL();
          imageUrl4 = await snapshot4.ref.getDownloadURL();

          uploadProduct(
            images: imageUrl1,
            images2: imageUrl2,
            images3: imageUrl3,
            images4: imageUrl4,
          );
```

---

An error occurs before uploading images to firebase storage.
Any solutions?

Price money: $2 (PayPal)

Comment: The error means the file doesn't exist, have you checked if it exists or not? Your getting the image from the gallery app?

Comment: yes from gallery. And it was working fine till this morning and now it sucks!

Comment: And temporary image picked fro gallery is also shown, but not uploading

Comment: can you give more than 2$, but bank transfer because paypal is forbidden here :(

Comment: Solved now by me! nice to meet u.....lol lol

Comment: need to delete app and re-install again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a problem of flutter clean or i just did  delete app and re-install it  again :)
Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you added this line

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

in your android/app/build.gradle